# Need a script to iterate over files and execute a command

Tags: python, networking, iteration, rendering

Please bear with me, I've not used python before, and I'm trying to get some rendering done as quick as possible and getting stopped in my tracks with this.

I'm outputting the .ifd files to a network drive (Z:), and they are stored in a folder structure like;

```
Z:  
 - \0001 
 - \0002 
 - \0003
```

I need to iterate over the ifd files within a single folder, but the number of files is not static so there also needs to be a definable range (1-300, 1-2500, etc). The script therefore has to be able to take an additional two arguments for a start and end range.

On each iteration it executes something called 'mantra' using this statement;

```
mantra -f file.FRAMENUMBER.ifd outputFile.FRAMENUMBER.png
```

I've found a script on the internet that is supposed to do something similar;

```
import sys, os

#import command line args
args = sys.argv

# get args as string
szEndRange = args.pop()
szStartRange = args.pop()

#convert args to int
nStartRange = int(szStartRange, 10);
nEndRange = int(szEndRange, 10);
nOrd = len(szStartRange);

#generate ID range
arVals = range(nStartRange, nEndRange+1);


for nID in arVals:
   szFormat = 'mantra -V a -f testDebris.%%(id)0%(nOrd)dd.ifd' % {"nOrd": nOrd};
   line = szFormat % {"id": nID};
   os.system(line);
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't get it to work. It seems to iterate, and do something - but it looks like it's just spitting out ifds into a different folder somewhere.

## TLDR;

I need a script which will at least take two arguments;

- *startFrame*
- *endFrame*

and from those create a *frameRange*, which is then used to iterate over all ifd files executing the following command;

- mantra -f fileName.currentframe.ifd fileName.currentFrame.png

If I were able to specify the filename and the files directory and output directory that'd be great too. I've tried manually doing that but there must be some convention to that I don't know as it was coming up with errors when I tried (stopping at the colon).

If anyone could hook me up or point me in the right direction that'd be swell. I know I should try and learn python, but I'm at my wits end with the rendering and need a helping hand.

Comment: You say that the number of files is non static and that a range needs to be provided. Does this mean that it would be sufficient for a program to discover the number of files in the folder instead?

Comment: I would only have the ifd files in the folder itself so I'm assuming that would be fine yes.

Comment: your manta command is missing the `.png` from your example.

Comment: The example I posted I don't really understand, so could you be more specific please. Is it just missing the file extension or the secondary argument? Thanks.

Comment: what does `mantra` do? it looks like it is `mantra -f [in-file] [out-file]` in which case when you render your command it is missing the second file arg. and that may do nothing.

Comment: Mantra is the rendering engine and that's the two inputs it takes, you got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os, subprocess, sys

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print('Must have 2 arguments!')
    print('Correct usage is "python answer.py input_dir output_dir" ')
    exit()

input_dir = sys.argv[1]
output_dir = sys.argv[2]
input_file_extension = '.txt'
cmd = 'currentframe'

# iterate over the contents of the directory
for f in os.listdir(input_dir):
    # index of last period in string
    fi = f.rfind('.')
    # separate filename from extension
    file_name = f[:fi]
    file_ext = f[fi:]
    # create args
    input_str = '%s.%s.ifd' % (os.path.join(input_dir, file_name), cmd)
    output_str =  '%s.%s.png' % (os.path.join(output_dir + file_name), cmd)
    cli_args = ['mantra', '-f', input_str, output_str]
    #call function
    if subprocess.call(cli_args, shell=True):
        print('An error has occurred with command "%s"' % ' '.join(cli_args))
```

This should be sufficient for you to either use currently or with slight modification.

Comment: Cheers Austin, that seems to work a treat if I omit the cmd = currentFrame from the input and output str. It was my way of representing the framenumber as a variable not a actual string.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifically inputting a start and end range you could just do:

```
import os

path, dirs, files = os.walk("/Your/Path/Here").next()
nEndRange = len(files)

#generate ID range    
arVals = range(1, nEndRange+1);
```

The command `os.walk()` counts the # of files in the folder that you specified.

Although, an even easier way of getting your desired output is like this:

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir('dirname'):
    szFormat = 'mantra -f ' + filename + ' outputFile.FRAMENUMBER.png'
    line = szFormat % {"id": filename}; # you might need to play around with this formatting
    os.system(line);
```

Because `os.listdir()` iterates through the specified directory and `filename` is every file in that directory, so you don't even need to count them.

Comment: Many thanks for the help, when I get the chance I'm going to look over everything so I can get it in my head. Cheers! Also, nice nickname ;)

Answer (score 0):

a little help building the command.

```
for nID in arVals:
   command = 'mantra -V a -f '
   infile = '{0}.{1:04d}.ifd '.format(filename, id)
   outfile = '{0}.{1:04d}.png '.format(filename, id)              
   os.system(command + infile + outfile);
```

and definitely use `os.walk` or `os.listdir` like @logic recommends

```
for file in os.listdir("Z:"):
   filebase = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
   command = 'mantra -V a -f {0}.ifd {0}.png'.format(filebase)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the help, when I get the chance I'm going to look over everything so I can get it in my head. Cheers!